# Getting nullpointerexception for bitmap.getWidth() when reading image from sdcard

Tags: android, image, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I read an image from sd card with BitmapFactory:

```
String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/yourdollar/img001.jpg"; 
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options);
```

If I write:

```
Log.i("width and height: ", bm.getWidth() + " " + bm.getHeight());
```

I get a nullpointer exception. I tried to scale with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` but I get the same error. After it I am processing the bitmap so I would like to have a bitmap in the end that has any width or height, because it seems like I didn't give parameters for the bitmap. But I cannot scale it, so how can I get this image as a bitmap with a width of 500 and a height of 500?

***UPDATE

```
 buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) { // <5>
        preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);

            Intent intentstart = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, Intent2.class);
          startActivity(intentstart);

      }
    });
```

Okay here is the thing. This button takes a picture with the camera then change activity. If I do this way, the app does not have time to create the so when I use it in my second activity to read it, it throws nullpointerexception. So I got tricky (and wrong as well) and put:

```
preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);

try {
        Thread.sleep(1200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       Intent intentstart = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, Intent2.class);
      startActivity(intentstart);
```

So it has 1.2 seconds to create the file, then change activity. Is there any way to check if the file created or not? Of course if its true then it should change activity.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Your path myJpgPath should be wrong

Comment: It works on two phones, on the third it throws it, so the path is correct.

Comment: The path is okay on two other phones, but the file and directory dont exist. I updated my question.

Comment: I'm guessing you getting a NPL, because the bitmap itself is null. Check if this is the case. If this is so, that would mean you are either saving the bitmap wrongly or reading it wrongly.

Comment: I skipped the sleep(1200), it is really weird because it does not create the bitmap in 1.2 secs. This happens on the fastest phone amongst the phones I tried on... So I can only step to the next activity if the file exists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just check whether your image in your required directory `/sdcard/yourdollar/img001.jpg` And, Just try like this -

```
String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/yourdollar/img001.jpg"; 
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath);
```

and get image height & width in your Logcat

```
Log.i("width and height: ", bm.getWidth() + " " + bm.getHeight());
```

Comment: Hmm. okay, it is weird. Both the file and directory dont exist, while my app creates them on two other phones. Is there any way to check if a file is created? I will update my question.

Comment: I accept your answer because the root of the problem was actually this. Anyway I put the intentstart to another place. It is in the `finally` of the try/catch block.